# Configuration for .Net application

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, app-config

I have very little knowledge of .Net programming, i got my software developed on .Net platform, Now i have installed the software but it prompts an error like `Error in LibraryManager.SelectActive()`,I have my database configured on local sql server and using windows authentication for it.THe xml configuration file is like `<add key="ConnectionString" value="Password=;User ID=salman;Initial Catalog=LogoStick;Data Source=symbol;"/>` with `symbol` as a DSN name.

Please tell me where i am doing it wrong ???

Comment: Is it possible to paste the stacktrace out here.

Comment: are you supplying a password, or is it blank?

Comment: its blank `<add key="ConnectionString" value="Password=;User ID=salman;Initial Catalog=demo2939;Data Source=localhost\symbol"/>`

Comment: Check where in code is that exception thrown. One way is you can review the stacktrace to find out. Another way is search your code for the particular error string (or partial): `Error in LibraryManager.SelectActive()`

Comment: I dont have the code,This is installed as software via wizard...

Answer (score 0):

your connection string is

```
Server =myServerName\theInstanceName; Database =myDataBase; Trusted_Connection =True;
```

for the windows authentication

For refence you can check : [Database Connectionstrings](http://www.dofactory.com/Connect/Connect.aspx#_self16x)

for Connection strings : [Connection strings for SQL Server 2005](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005)

Comment: This is the built-in xml configuration setting `<add key="ConnectionString" value="Password=;User ID=;Initial Catalog=LogoStick;Data Source=" />` if remove or add a tag it says `unrecognized tag..`

Comment: @Uzma Khan  - check for the link pasted by me

Comment: Can i create an sql trusted connection? instead of using windows authentication.n how ??